# Django - get or create dynamically objects with dictionary

Tags: django

Is it possible to use get_or_create to dynamically create/get objects passing a dictionary in which some fields wont be present like in the example?

What would be the best way to do something like this?

```
class Car(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    drivers = models.ManyToManyField(Driver, related_name='cars')

class Driver(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

################
driver = Driver.objects.create(id='foo')
for row in cars:
     # Dictionary might be {'id': foo, 'brand': ford} so without a name field
     dictionary = {
       key:value
       for key,value in row
       if value is not None
     }

     # Passing the dictionary with keys/fields values/values
     car_object, created = Car.objects.get_or_create(driver, **dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may do that almost the way you post, only change the many to many field:

```
car_object, created = Car.objects.get_or_create(**dictionary)
car_object.drivers.add(driver)
```